# leading vs line-height in CSS

Tags: css

So in traditional page layout programs, when you do leading, it doesn't effect the first line of a paragraph. However, if you use line-height in CSS, whatever your number is, that will effect the first line. Is there any way to mimic desktop leading in CSS? Basically, I want to only have line-height apply to the subsequent lines, not the first line.

Comment: I ended up doing a negative margin top, and this resolved the issue I was having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
.class {
    line-height: 1.5;
}
.class::first-line {
    line-height: 1;
}

/* If legacy browsers must be supported */
.class:first-line { 
    line-height: 1;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/::first-line

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-firstline

Comment: Although this is interesting, and it does stop the first line moving, the result looks pretty bad. The first and second are now closer together.

Comment: That first-line thing helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I can do the traditional "leading" by setting a negative margin-top, like this:

```
h3 { 
color: #fff;
font-weight: normal;
padding-bottom: 0px;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 22px;
margin-top:-1px;
}
```

Comment: This will only solve the problem if the first line of the paragraph is following a heading; if the paragraph is paragraph 2 or more under that heading, your solution will not work. It is, though, a workaround, which – dubitously – could be applied if `::first-line` for some reason couldn’t be used.